# Typed XML Update in SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, xml, namespaces, xquery, updates

I have 3rd party table with XML column and I need to change the recipient value in the *value* if the key\string = 'recipient'. Here is a slice of the original XML with 2 items:

```
DECLARE @myDoc XML  
SET @myDoc = '<Root>
<item>
    <key>
      <string>subject</string>
    </key>
    <value>
      <anyType xmlns:q1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:p5="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" p5:type="q1:string">test subject</anyType>
    </value>
  </item>
<item>
    <key>
      <string>recipient</string>
    </key>
    <value>
      <anyType xmlns:q1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:p5="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" p5:type="q1:string">prodops@company.com</anyType>
    </value>
  </item>
</Root>'  
  
SET @myDoc.modify('  
  declare namespace q1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"; declare namespace p5="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";    
  replace value of (/q1:Root/q1:item/q1:value/p5:type="q1:string")[1]  
  with ("devops@company.com")  
')  
SELECT @myDoc
```

I have kind of hacked my way to this point - XML is not my strong suit. Based on BOL, I need to do something with namespace in the `modify()`? Right? I'm missing an if statement I am sure but just a mystery as to how to de-reference that value for recipient. Someone has done this before - I am sure. The goal is to incorporate into a post-restore script after refreshing production data to test.

Note that this fails as-is with

> Msg 2337, Level 16, State 1, Line 125
> XQuery [modify()]: The target of 'replace' must be at most one node, found 'xs:boolean ?'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to specify `text()` to replace the inner text of a node.** You also need to reference the `anyType` node, which you have not.

By the looks of things, none of the relevant nodes actually use the namespaces, so we don't need them at all.

```sql
SET @myDoc.modify('  
  replace value of (/Root/item[key[string[text()="recipient"]]]/value/anyType/text())[1]  
  with ("devops@company.com")  
');
```

**Explanation:**

- Descend to `/Root`, no namespace needed
- Descend to `/item[` with a predicate...
- ... must have `key[` node ...
- ... which has `string[` node ...
- ... which has inner `text()="recipient"]]]`
- Back to the original `item` we descend `/value` then `/anyType` then inner `/text()`
- All bracketed to `[1]` to ensure a single node

Comment: Charlieface - you are now GODFACE! I've done some xquery on nodes before but this plopped on my desk to do and I simply dont have the time to deepdive on this. You just saved me a few DAYS I think.

Answer (score 0):

The title of the question specifies "Typed XML Update in SQL Server table".

The provided XML is not bound by any XSD schema. That's why that XML is not typed. A real typed XML is updated differently.

Please try the following solution. It has the following:

- Somewhat simpler XPath predicate expression.
- Using SQL variable for a new value.

All credit goes to @Charlieface.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @myDoc XML =
N'<Root>
    <item>
        <key>
            <string>subject</string>
        </key>
        <value>
            <anyType xmlns:q1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                     xmlns:p5="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                     p5:type="q1:string">test subject</anyType>
        </value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <key>
            <string>recipient</string>
        </key>
        <value>
            <anyType xmlns:q1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                     xmlns:p5="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                     p5:type="q1:string">prodops@company.com</anyType>
        </value>
    </item>
</Root>';

DECLARE @anyType VARCHAR(30) = 'devops@company.com';
  
SET @myDoc.modify('  
  replace value of (/Root/item[key/string/text()="recipient"]/value/anyType/text())[1]  
  with (sql:variable("@anyType"))  
');

-- test 
SELECT @myDoc;
```

Comment: Thanks Yitzhak - nice touch to put it all together as you did. I hope this helps others as well. I couldnt find an exact problem like this on SO. Most are standard xml and answers in BOL etc.